# Triggering text area by clicking related select/checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a form in which one of the questions consists of a checkbox and a textarea. I removed the standard view of checkboxes and made my own on their place. I now want to integrate the trigger of the checkbox click makes the textbox active.

I'm using jQuery and I don't know pure JS well. Unfortunately I don't have opportunity to change the HTML in my case.

```js
var $other = $('input[type=text][placeholder="your text"]');
var otherOption = $other.attr('name');
$('.form-check-other > .form-check-input').after('<label class="form-check-label" for="' + otherOption + '">');
$other.off('change');
$other.on('input');
$other.on('blur');
```

```css
label {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #303030;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

label {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
  line-height: 180%;
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
  width: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  left: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label:after {
  content: '';
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #673F9A #673F9A;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.8rem;
  left: 0.2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(2) rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
  color: #673F9A
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #606060;
  text-transform: none;
  border: 2px solid #ededed;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

input[type="text"].form-control:focus {
  border: 2px solid #673F9A;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.form-check-other {
  position: relative;
}

.form-check-other .form-check-label {
  position: absolute!important;
  left: 0;
}

.form-check-label,
.form-check-other {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="construction and real estate" value="construction and real estate">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="construction and real estate">construction and real estate</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-other">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="other_option_response" value="__other_option__">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="other_option_response" value="" placeholder="your text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you require you can hook a `change` event handler to the checkbox which sets the state of the `disabled` property of its sibling textbox.

Also note that it's invalid HTML to have spaces within `id` attributes, so I replaced them with underscores in the following example.

```js
// this should *REALLY* be in the HTML, not hacked in using JS.
var $other = $('input[type="text"][placeholder="your text"]');
var otherOption = $other.attr('name');
$('.form-check-other > .form-check-input').after(`<label class="form-check-label" for="${otherOption}">`);

// toggle disabled state
$('.form-check-input').on('change', e => {
  $(e.target).siblings(':text').prop('disabled', !e.target.checked).focus();
});
```

```css
label {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #303030;
  letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

label {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
  line-height: 180%;
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
  width: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  left: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label:after {
  content: '';
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #673F9A #673F9A;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.8rem;
  left: 0.2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(2) rotate(-45deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
  color: #673F9A
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #606060;
  text-transform: none;
  border: 2px solid #ededed;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

input[type="text"].form-control:focus {
  border: 2px solid #673F9A;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 1.6rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.form-check-other {
  position: relative;
}

.form-check-other .form-check-label {
  position: absolute!important;
  left: 0;
}

.form-check-label,
.form-check-other {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="construction_and_real_estate" value="construction and real estate" />
  <label class="form-check-label" for="construction_and_real_estate">construction and real estate</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-other">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="other_option_response" value="__other_option__" />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="other_option_response" value="" placeholder="your text" disabled />
</div>
```

Comment: what about HTML - I translated content of attribute from another language and forgot for a second about syntax

Comment: It would be perfect if you make a feature to make this script work for the select button too.

Comment: In that case change `:text` in the selector to `:input`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the click on element and then use nextAll to find next input.

And then, you use focus and blur to fire on your input.

I also used class to check if click element was already clicked or not

```js
var $other = $('input[type=text][placeholder="your text"]');
var otherOption = $other.attr('name');
$('.form-check-other > .form-check-input').after('<label class="form-check-label" for="' + otherOption + '">');

$('.form-check-input').change(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
    $(this).addClass('checked').nextAll('input[name=other_option_response]:first').focus();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('checked').nextAll('input[name=other_option_response]:first').blur();
  }
});
```

```css
label {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #303030;
    letter-spacing: 0.04rem;
    line-height: 2.5rem;
}
label {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
    line-height: 180%;
}
input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px
}
input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  height: 1.4rem;
  width: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5rem;
  left: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input+label:after {
  content: '';
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #673F9A #673F9A;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.8rem;
  left: 0.2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(2) rotate(-45deg);
}
input[type="checkbox"].form-check-input:checked+label:after {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
     color: #673F9A
}
.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    height: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #606060;
    text-transform: none;
    border: 2px solid #ededed;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 0.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
 }
input[type="text"].form-control:focus {
    border: 2px solid #673F9A;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 0 1.6rem;
    margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
 }
 .form-check-other {
    position: relative;
 }
 .form-check-other .form-check-label{
   position: absolute!important;
   left: 0;
 }
 .form-check-label, .form-check-other {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 2.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="construction and real estate" value="construction and real estate">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="construction and real estate">construction and real estate</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-other">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="other_option_response" value="__other_option__"> 
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="other_option_response" value="" placeholder="your text">
  </div>
```